# restrict second login while first login session is active

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-farm, stateserver

In case of Asp.NET web application, using state server session and web farm; How to restrict user from login multiple times. If user is already logged in, He shouldn't be allowed to login using the same credential from different browser. 
I have found a link to automatically log out previous session [Single Session Enforcement](http://geekswithblogs.net/Frez/archive/2010/05/17/preventing-a-user-from-having-multiple-concurrent-sessions.aspx). But the requirement is to keep the first session alive rather than logging him out. whenever second session tries to login, he should get error message stating "User is already logged in".

We have session time out of 20 min.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to state what version of ASP.NET MVC you're talking about. If you're on ASP.NET MVC 5, you'd do this via ASP.NET Identity.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to set `IsLoggedin` status in you DB. While login you have to check this status. If it's `true` then user is already logged in. And while `logout` you have to change this to false.

If user closed the browser

```
 $(function () {
        //logic to signout user when he closes browser
        window.onclick = function () {
            clicked = true;
        };

        window.onunload = function () {
            if (clicked == false) {
                $.get("/account/logout");
            }
        };
    });
```

In logout you can check `if (GetUserContext() != null)` then change `IsLoggedIn` status.

Comment: But how will we manage in case user closes the browser or the session expires because of inactivity of 20 mins?

Comment: You have to add the code on session expire. For browser close check my edit

Comment: Window.Onclick [Window.OnClick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onclick) fires even on redirecting from one page to another, Also for the code shared by you, it will be executed on any mouse click on the window. What is GetUserContext()? Is it `HttpContext.User`??

Comment: On my side it is working fine. When I click on windows close button it calls `logout` action. Yes it's `HttpContext.User`

Comment: Add given script in in `_Layout.cshtml` page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:for `currect browser`

```
if (!Session.IsNewSession && Request.UrlReferrer == null)
{
    // new 
}
```

Comment: How will this work if the user login from different machines?